# How to return to the main python script after using exec function?

Tags: python, scripting

I have to two python scripts that I want to execute; scriptA.py and scriptB.py

My code is as follows:

```
sys.argv = [Path_of_scriptA,'arg1','arg2']
exec(open(Path_of_scriptA).read())

#my code exits here!

sys.argv = [Path_of_scriptB,'arg1','arg2','arg3']
exec(open(Path_of_scriptB).read())

#end
```

My code exits after the first execute command. However, I would like my script to run until the #end.

Any ideas?

Comment: Or use `subprocess` if they aren't amenable to importing? `exec` is almost never the tool you need; it's for exceptional circumstances.

Comment: Yes I can't import because they aren't amenable. I can however, use `subprocess`. But I am still curious as to why the `exec` exits the main script and how to overcome it.

Comment: It could be that your first exec program is throwing an error that is unhandled by the `exec` command (that you won't get since it returns no output). Using `subprocess` [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) may help identify the issue. It's got better error handling than `exec` for future work too.